# Cannot remove underscores mapping over an object using regex

Tags: javascript, regex, object

I've run into questions similar to this one, but they generally pertain on how to remove an underscore whereas I am having the issue of removing the underscore in a for loop. When console logging in my function it will show that the fields I want changed do in fact change but when I return the object it only returns an object where all keys have snake case. I think this may be a scope issue but after playing around with the different placement of variables I keep getting stuck. Below is an example of the original object I would like to change:

```
const originalObj = {
  accountNumber: '12345',
  company: [
    {
      address: {
        line1: '123',
        line2: 'Spring Street'
      }
    }
  ],
  ownerInfo: [
    {
      firstName: 'John',
      lastName: 'Doe'
      enrollment: '2015-10-15'
    }
  ],
  tax: {
    code: '12345'
  }
}
```

Using the npm package `change-case-object` I am able to successfully change all keys with camel case to snake case. However, I do not want any key that has a numeric value to include an underscore (like with the cases of line1 and line2). With this function

```
import changeCaseObject from 'change-case-object';

export function restructure(originalObj) {
  const regex = /\d/g;
  let newObj;
  if(typeof originalObj === "object"){
    newObj = changeCaseObject.snakeCase(originalObj);
    for(const key in newObj){
      if(typeof newObj[key] === "object" && newObj[key] !== null){
        restructure(newObj[key])
        //if the value is an object use recursion
      } else {
        if(regex.test(key)){
          let newKey = key.replace(/_/g, '');
          newObj.newKey = newObj.key;
          delete newObj.key;
        }
      }
    }
  }
  return newObj;
}
```

When I add a console log in the case where the key matches the regex, it will show that "line_1" does in fact change to "line1" along with "line_2". However when returning `newObj` it just returns the object in which *all* values now have snake case (as shown below)

```
{
  account_number: '12345',
  company: [
    {
      address: {
        line_1: '123',
        line_2: 'Spring Street'
      }
    }
  ],
  owner_info: [
    {
      first_name: 'John',
      last_name: 'Doe'
      enrollment: '2015-10-15'
    }
  ],
  tax: {
    code: '12345'
  }
}
```

I feel like there is something very simple that I am overlooking but defining `newObj` outside of the if else statement has not led to success either. Thank you for your time.

Comment: key is const, read more here:https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/const

Comment: @PoulBak Ah that does make sense, however I changed originalObj to let but it still results in the same error :/